# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, copy

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{

BOOL success;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success) return;

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];


 NSError *errr;

 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:&errr];

 NSLog( @"Error >>>>>>>> %@",errr);

}
```

Using the above code database file created in iOS 5.0 simulator, but has no sql queries.
If using iOS 4.3 simulator, it works properly working.   Below error displayed when running te app.

```
Error >>>>>>>> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x6a53860 {NSUserStringVariant=(
Copy
), NSFilePath=/Users/sj/Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator/5.0/Applications/D8BF5CC1-5690-4897-A3D7-252D915D399E/MyTest.app/MyTestDB.sql, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/sj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D8BF5CC1-5690-4897-A3D7-252D915D399E/Documents/MyTestDB.sql, NSUnderlyingError=0x6a65510 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

Comment: Read the entire message.

Comment: If i delete the app in the simulator and run the code.  I deleted database in the documents folder and run the code. Same thing happen. I cant understand why its only for iOS 5 simulator.

Comment: I wonder if you're somehow "touching" that file and causing it to be created before you attempt the copy.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Before calling the checkAndCreateDatabase function there are some codes for creating tabs. There are few sql queries in those viewControllers. Because of these classes, it created empty database with same name.

Comment: Just to help whoever comes to need.

Error 516 is NSFileWriteFileExistsError

Comment: @Frade, That's exactly what I was after thanks! I knew exactly what the error was, just wanted a future proof way to check for it.

Comment: @James Webster I have posted an answer on this but the owner has deleted it, for no apparent reason.. 
Check first if the file exists `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:your_WRITABLE_Path]`

Comment: When it says "deleted by owner" and it's your answer.. you're the owner :P You should be able to undelete it. As it happens, I can see your deleted answer. It is useful, I wondered why it was deleted.

Comment: Btw, instead of checking if the file exists first, I just allow the error to populate and check the code. If the code is NSFileWriteFileExistsError, I don't show a message.